# Is it possible to append two things at once as a list within a list? (Python)

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to simulate a list of 2x1 matrices. What I need to do is to be able to append two floats as a list within a list, like:

[[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]...]

Is it possible to do this in python?

Sorry if I've formatted this incorrecty.

EDIT: I'm attempting to find the covariance matrix for a class of data by hand (so no numpy). The function that I have so far is:

```
def covariance(matrix,mean):
    temp = []
    for i in range(0,len(matrix)):
        temp.append([(matrix[i][0] - mean[0])])  #x
        temp.append([(matrix[i][1] - mean[1])]) #y
        #print(temp[0])
    print(temp)
```

the matrix file simulates a 2x1 matrix for an x and y coordinate corresponding to the data. So it looks like the list I mentioned earlier. I'd like to retain that format when I append the two values to the "temp" list.

Comment: Can you give example of what you are triyng to achcieve? Calling append twice does not work?

Comment: Just `temp.append([(matrix[i][0] - mean[0]), (matrix[i][1] - mean[1])])`. Btw, using a tuple seems more reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

Lets say those two floats are:

```
x = 1.23
y = 4.56
list = [[4,5]]
sublist = [x,y]
list.append(sublist)
print list
```

output:

```
    python main.py                                                                                                                                              
[[4, 5], [1.23, 4.56]]
```

Comment: You could also use a tuple as the inner list.

Comment: @yesthisisme Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have something like:

```
coords = []
x = 1.2
y = 1.3
```

you can do something like:

```
coords.append([x, y])
```

Which will create the internal list on the fly

Alternatively, make `coords` a class which extends `list` and overrides `.append()` to accept two arguments and internally calls `super(coords_class, self).append([x, y])`, then you could do something like

```
coords.append(x, y)
```